# How to get to HTTPServer class from RequestHandler?

Tags: tornado

I have class based on HTTPServer:

```
class MyServer(tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.my_prog = subprocess.Popen(
            ['python', 'myprog.py'],
            stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
```

and view:

```
class MessageHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, some_data):

        # some stuff and
        # here I would like to get to 
        # MyServer.my_prog
```

I want to send via communicate message to my_prog from view. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTPServer is not exposed to the handlers. Why are you subclassing HTTPServer? It's not really designed for customization in this way. It would be more typical to use a subclass of Application for this purpose (the Application is available to the handlers as `self.application`).